# Error while compiling ejs, the error is on local system

Tags: node.js, express, module, ejs

Can anyone help me with below error.

I am getting this error on local but on server its working fine.

Have tried changing include ../PATH/files.ejs to include('../PATH/files.ejs') this removes error but not able to print content on that file.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in /PATH/index.ejs while compiling ejs  
If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (/PATH/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:626:12)
    at Object.compile (/PATH/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:366:16)
    at handleCache (/PATH/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:215:18)
    at tryHandleCache (/PATH/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:254:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/PATH/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:459:10)
    at View.render (/PATH/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/PATH/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/PATH/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/PATH/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/PATH/node_modules/express-ejs-layouts/lib/express-layouts.js:77:18)
    at res_data (/PATH/front_system.js:248:17)
    at /PATH/front_system.js:218:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/PATH/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/PATH/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/PATH/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/PATH/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /PATH/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/PATH/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/PATH/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (/PATH/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:110:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/PATH/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not like a forum, where you mark a solved thread by adding "[RESOLVED]" in the title. Here, if no one gave the answer, then you have to add the answer and mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by changing:

From

```
<% include ../PATH/files.ejs %>
```

To

```
<%- include('../PATH/files.ejs') %>
```